# Rating system not displaying correctly

Tags: xml, xslt

i dont understand why the output is different from what i see on the website ( http://dabblet.com/gist/1722368) Can anyone help me? please. Trying to create multiple rating systems in a page through xslt/xml.

This is my xslt code:

```
 <div class="rating">
                <xsl:element name="input">
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="value">5</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">myrating</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <label>☆</label>

                <xsl:element name="input">
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="value">4</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">myrating</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <label>☆</label>
                <xsl:element name="input">
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="value">3</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">myrating</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <label>☆</label>
                <xsl:element name="input">
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="value">2</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">myrating</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <label>☆</label>
                <xsl:element name="input">
                  <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="value">1</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">myrating</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <label>☆</label>
              </div>
```

My css code :

```
 .rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;

    }
    .rating > label{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;
    }
    .rating > *:hover,
    .rating > *:hover ~ label,
    .rating:not(:hover) > input:checked ~ label{
    color: transparent;
    }
    .rating > *:hover:before,
    .rating > *:hover ~ label:before,
    .rating:not(:hover) > input:checked ~ label:before {
    content: "\2605";

    left: 0;
    color: gold;
    }

    .rating > input {
    margin-left:-1.1em;
    margin-right:0;
    top:3px;
    width:1.1em;
    height:1.1em;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing has nothing to do with XSLT.

I see that you changed the original page, replacing *span* tags with *label*.

Apparently you forgot, that *label* tag must have *for* attribute with value
equal to *id* of the *input* tag it is connected with.

So I added *id* attributes to *input* tags and respective *for* attributes to *label* tags and it works.

Check the working example at jsfiddle (6to6zfw2).